# Exporting and Importing RData with a time variable after using dcast

Tags: r, panel

I'm trying to export a data frame into RData and import it into another R script. Usually that is no problem with write and read table. However, after using dcast on a data frame with a year variable, write.table does not put "..." around every entry in the table but does so in an almost arbitrary way which creates errors.

**Create Data:**

```
rm(list = ls(all=T))
setwd("yourpath")
geo <- c("a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b")
time <-c("2000Q4","2000Q4","2000Q3","2000Q3","2000Q4","2000Q4","2000Q3","2000Q3")
indic_na <- c("x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y")
value <- c(5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
Data <- as.data.frame(cbind(geo,time,indic_na, value))
```

**Problematic Code:**

```
library(zoo)
library(reshape2)
Data$time = as.yearqtr(Data$time)
Data <- dcast(Data, geo + time ~ indic_na, value.var = "value")
write.table(Data,file="Data.RData")

Data2 <- read.table("yourpath/Data.RData")
```

you will get the error message "line 1 did not have 6 elements" which is strange because its only supposed to have 4. But if you look at the RData file in a text editor you see that exporting did not work well at all:

```
"geo" "time" "x" "y"
"1" "a" 2000 Q3 "7" "11"
"2" "a" 2000 Q4 "5" "9"
"3" "b" 2000 Q3 "8" "12"
"4" "b" 2000 Q4 "6" "10"
```

while there should be "..." around every element. The time variables, however, have none. If I did not use dcast on my dataframe, this problem does not appear, if I don't use as.yearqr, there is no problem either.

Any help with this issue would be great!

**Edit:** 
both comments work, thanks! The first one in code for noobs like me:

```
save(Data, file="Data.RData")
load("Data.RData")
```

Comment: Use `save` and `load` instead of `read/write.table`.

Comment: Or do `Data$time = as.character(as.yearqtr(Data$time))` instead of `Data$time = as.yearqtr(Data$time)`